# No ecs task definition (or empty definition file) found in environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

### System

CI/CD using `AWS CodePipeline`:

- `AWS CodeBuild` connect Github 2
- `AWS Beanstalk` using images from `ECR`, Multi-container docker platform

### Error

```
Deployment completed, but with errors: Failed to deploy application. No ecs task definition (or empty definition file) found in environment
```

### Elastic Beanstalk Upload Application

```
app.zip
  |
  --Dockerrun.aws.json
  |
  --nginx
     |
     --default.conf
```

#### `Dockerrun.aws.json`

Content [here](https://pastebin.com/yXy71rS4).

I tried to deploy only Elastic Beanstalk using images after building and file `app.zip`, and surprisingly it worked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the content of `Dockerrun.aws.json`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/yXy71rS4. I removed the env and image for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue.

I thought that EB will read the file `Dockerrun.aws.json` from **zip** file I uploaded.
However, EB using the Docker platform read that file from the image. I put the file `Dockerrun` to the image and it worked.

Comment: Hi Leo, could you clarify what you meant by putting Dockerrun to the repo? I believe I have a similar issue. I have a `Dockerrun.aws.json` which is commited to my bitbucket repo but it still gives the same problem. Do you mean it has to be in ECR itself?

Comment: That's right. You can see an example here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker-glassfish-tutorial.html